# Puddletag format value formating all selected fields

Tags: music, mp3

I am a regular user of Puddletag and I recently tried to write an action to format a .mp3 files track tag to add a leading 0 to single digit value.

I did this by setting the action to use the format value function and with field set to title, and format string set to `$num(%track%, 2)` as shown below.
[image: image of function window as described above]

In theory this should only format the track value only, however in my case this formats all fields that are selected.

I am using Puddletag 1.2.0 on Ubuntu 19.10.

Thank you for any help you may provide.

**Full steps to reproduce**

1. Open Puddletag and navigate to folder with `.mp3` files.
2. Select any combination of fields.
3. Run the action described above.

Video should be uploaded [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hapdz.jpg)

Comment: That format and function looks, and works correctly, for me on puddletag 1.2.0. How are you selecting all of the tracks? Have you tried different ways of selecting the tracks? Any more details you might be able to provide?

Comment: @KevinBowen I am selecting all fields of all tracks, I am aware that it will work correctly if I only select the fields I want effected, however that can be inconvenient when I want to use more then one action, furthermore it is not how the program is meant to work.

Comment: I am unable to repro on Xubuntu 19.04, 19.10, and Mint 19.3 and Debian 10. I have selected multiple fields, single fields, Ctrl-A'd the fields, selected fields other that the track # with the function you indicated working successfully.

Comment: @KevinBowen Odd, I added proper reproduction steps and a Imgur video post of the process.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the added detail. I can repro when I use the function as a *Quick Action*; but, it works normally when I use the function as an *Action* or when I apply manually, as I had been doing. Perhaps a bug? https://github.com/keithgg/puddletag/issues

Comment: @KevinBowen Turns out that it is intentional, quote from [tutorial 2 on puddletag.net](https://docs.puddletag.net/source/tut2.html) "Quick Action runs an action as normal but ignores the fields defined in the functions and uses the selected cells.", I never actually knew what quick actions where for, I just use it because the button is easier to click on for me lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @KevinBowen for helping me figure this out.

Turns out that it is intentional, quote from [tutorial 2 on puddletag.net](https://docs.puddletag.net/source/tut2.html) "Quick Action runs an action as normal but ignores the fields defined in the functions and uses the selected cells.", I never actually knew what quick actions where for, I just use it because the button is easier to click on for me.

Comment: That seems...counter-intuitive, no? At least, you can still use 'Actions' to accomplish the same results and still create keyboard shortcuts if you wish. Good job sticking with finding the answer even it is a bit odd.

Comment: @KevinBowen It seems fairly normal to me, it's a extra bit of functionality, the name is odd though, I would have called it "selection action" or something along that line.

Comment: No. It is broken behavior and should be filed as a bug.